# Adding conditional statement to the number of times a loop is executed

Tags: c++

How do we add a conditional statement that depends on the number of times a loop is executed
For example:- 
if a loop is executed 1 time, do this
If a loop is executed 2 times, do this
OR
If a loop is executed even number of times, do this
If a loop is executed odd number of times, do this
Also, How do we create a loop that executes only odd number of times meaning if it ran 1 time first then the next time it will run 3 times and the next time, it runs 5 times...and so on until it is executed n*2-1 times.

Comment: *"How do we add a conditional statement that depends on the number of times a loop is executed"* have you tried an `if` statement?

Comment: Is the conditional statement *after* the loop or during?

Comment: Have a counter for the loop execution, and use it. You usually get a de-facto one with `for` construct.

Comment: The conditional statement is after the loop

Comment: And I don't know why I got 5 down votes. It would be great if the ones who down voted it also comment why they did it.

Comment: _Also, How do we create a loop that executes only odd number of times meaning if it ran 1 time first then the next time it will run 3 times and the next time, it runs 5 times...and so on until it is executed n*2-1 times._ Sounds like two nested loops: `for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) for (int j = 0, m = 2 * i + 1; j < m; ++j) { }`.

Comment: May be, because your question lacks a code attempt (smelling like "Please, write the code.") and is a bit unclear worded. (Just a guess - I didn't down vote.)

Comment: Oh that one makes sense, thanks scheff

Comment: "*This question does not show any research effort*" - literally from the description on the downvote button. Also, in general it would be a good thing to figure out which programming language you're using and tag the question accordingly.

Comment: I recently started studying c++ (just school level programming), I only posted it here cuz I had doubts and I did do a lot of thinking before putting my question up here so I think it's rude of others do down vote and not give a reason

Comment: Then remove the C tag. C and C++ are two different languages. Add some code, at least a [mcve].

Comment: @Robin_Dabank your question is public. SO is meant for all users to be able to find answers. Without downvoting, not appropriate questions would show up in searching - we don't want that.

Comment: Site policy disagrees with you. In fact, I got suspended once for leaving comments on questions instead of just downvoting and moving on. So unexplained downvotes are part of the SO concept.

Comment: @melpomene Although, I remember having read a long discussion on Meta whether comments on down-votes could be forced somehow. If I got it right the essential counter-argument was that down-voted might do revenge down-voting...

Comment: lol i also got tons of down votes yesterday for posting a recommendation(opinion based) question. had to remove that post. if you got your answer, you can remove the post

Comment: Thanks, I got both the answers. I will just remove the post. Sorry for causing trouble.

Comment: @Robin_Dabank Removing your post after you get an answer may lead to a question ban.

Comment: Downvotes are presumably because you are not clear. Eg "if a loop is executed 1 time,"--What does that mean? Is that if statement to appear after the loop finishes, or inside the loop to execute something on only the first iteration? Etc etc all through. You don't even use proper grammar. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. PS Clarify via edits, not comments. Ask one question per post. (It's not clear whether this is reasonably one question, because it's not clear.) See [ask], other [help] links & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Count variable.

```
int count=0;
Loop()
{
      count++;
}
if (count==1)
      do something;
else
      do something else;
if (count%2==0)    //count is even
      do this;
else               //count is odd
      do that;
```